# How does compiler optimisation done with respect to this code?

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-optimization, gcc4, gcc4.7

I am getting two different answers in two different compiler .

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define square(a) a*a
main()
{
    int a=3;
    printf("%d ",square(a++));
    printf("%d ",square(a--));
}
```

In gcc 4.x versions output is 9 and 25
In newer gcc 12 and 20 are the outputs
How are the newer compilers handling this compiler optimization?
I want to know about the volatile in such compiler optimization issues.

Comment: And read the first answer of the duplicate. It seems what your are doing is undefined behavior because there is no clean usage of the macro there.

Comment: Read about 'sequence point's. The duplicate question should point you in the right direction to understand what's behind your problem.